# Replace a body parameter based on value that client sent

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

I created a API in WSO2 integrator studio contain the below body to receive the application requests.

```
{"count": "2000",
"Name": "22312312"
  },
```

For responding to above request, I have to send the following JSON body toward the endpoint:

{"count": "2000",
"Name": "BANK"
},

As you can see, the difference between to bodies is about "NAME" value. In this scenario, each client send its own unique number in "Name" parameter, and I have to translate it into a String Name (in WSO2 Enterprise integrator) and send it to the endpoint.

How can I manage this in Integrator studio?

Comment: Is the mapping dynamic? Where do you keep the relation between the unique number and the String Name?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it. You can have the mappings in a LocalEntry and then use a combination of `Property` mediators and `Enrich` mediator to select the `Name` and replace the `Code`. Check the following.

**Local Entry**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="Mappings" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <Mappings xmlns="">
        <bank>
            <code>22312312</code>
            <name>bank</name>
        </bank>
        <bank>
            <code>22312313</code>
            <name>bank2</name>
        </bank>
        <bank>
            <code>22312314</code>
            <name>bank3</name>
        </bank>
    </Mappings>
</localEntry>
```

**API**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/bank" name="BankAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/code">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="get-property('Mappings')" name="localEntry" scope="default" type="OM"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.Name)" name="BankCode" scope="default"/>
            <property expression="$ctx:localEntry//bank[code = $ctx:BankCode]/name/text()" name="BankName"/>
            <enrich>
                <source type="property" clone="true" property="BankName"/>
                <target xpath="json-eval($.Name)"/>
            </enrich>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**Request and Response**

```json
{
    "count": "2000",
    "Name": "22312313"
}
```

```json
{
    "count": "2000",
    "Name": "bank2"
}
```

If your mapping is dynamic, for example, if you need to pass the code to another API and get the Name, you can still use the same logic above with the Enrich mediator. Instead of reading from the LocalEntry you can get the data from the API.